# Cannot prompt user using rm builtin prompt option -i with xargs and find

Tags: bash, find, rm, prompt, xargs

I am using **xargs** and **rm** with **find** in order to remove files that follow a specific pattern defined by find as follows:

```
touch file
find . -name file | xargs rm
```

Everything works fine with the above code, but if I enter the -i option to rm, then executing:

```
touch file
find . -name file | xargs rm -i
```

prints:

> rm: remove regular empty file ‘./file7’? user@host:$

without letting me enter y or n. Thus the file is not removed.

What's the problem here?

I am also aware of the xargs -p parameter which works but it is more general. That is, it prompts user to execute the specific command, which is not user-friendly.

EDIT: While using it in a shell script, I've found out that it executes the command I want but it also prints find's result, which is not preferable.

Also, when I pass the `ls file2` command to cmd variable, it does not specifically print the file2's specs. Same thing happens when I type
`rm -i file2` . It prompts me to delete every single file in the directory.

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch file{1..9}      # Create 9 files named file1,file2...file9
echo -n 'command: '  # Prompt user
read -e cmd             # read command
find . -exec ${cmd} '{}' +
```

The only solution I can think of is to prompt the user separately for their preferred pattern. Then store that pattern to a variable and pass it as an argument to **find** command's **-name** option.

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch file{1..9}     # Create 9 files named file1,file2...file9
echo -n 'command: '  # Prompt user for command
read -e cmd          # read command
echo -n 'pattern: '  # Prompt user for pattern
read -e pattern
find . -name "$pattern" -exec ${cmd} '{}' +
```

But even with this solution, **find**'s output is still printed and if the pattern field is left empty (i.e., the user just does not want to use a pattern) then problems occur.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `stdin` (the standard input) for the command ran from `xargs` (in this case `rm`) is redirected from `/dev/null`, and the `stdin` is the file descriptor used by `rm` to obtain the user's confirmation.

You could use the `-a` option so that rm obtain the list of files from an intermediate file previously generated by the find command (the `-a` option makes `xargs` to let the `stdin` untouched), in any case, I understand this may not be what you really want since it requires the intermediate file.  A more straight approach similar to what you wanted can be obtained with the command below:

`for i in $(find . -name file); do rm -i "$i"; done`

Answer (score 4):

xargs reads data from stdin. When you use `rm -i` rm also tries to read the answer from stdin (try `touch test && echo y | r -i test ; ls test`) but stdin is closed by xargs (I assume) so rm reacts as if you had pressed ctrl-d at the prompt.

Another solution might be find's -exec option:

```
touch test
find . -name test -exec rm -i {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) `-ok` option for `find` to have it ask you whether or not to proceed with a command (other than the prompt it's just like `-exec`)

```
touch file
find . -name 'file' -ok rm -f {} \;
```

Output

```
< rm ... ./file > ? _
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     Just try that command

    find . -type f -iname filename -delete


  it is better to delete the need file.

   -type f ----> specific the file type ( file or directory or etc. )
   -iname  ----> ignore the case sensitive ( test or Test)
   -delete ----> its one of find command option, its delete files
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and was surprised when the command

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" | xargs rm
```

unexpectedly deleted read-only files that matched the pattern.

Only afterward did I find the explanation in the `rm` man page:

> if a file is unwritable, standard input is a terminal, and the -f or
> --force option is not given, or the -i or --interactive=always option is given, rm prompts the user for whether to remove the file.

One of the conditions to get the prompt is that standard input is a terminal, which is not true when you are piping output from another command to `rm`.

**IMPORTANT LESSON: if stdin is not a terminal, `rm` will remove read-only files without any warning!!**

In my case, the solution was to modify the `find` command to only return writable files:

```
find . -type f -writable -name "*.txt" | xargs rm
```